Why is shooting 3s better than shooting 2s, with a score-to-win?
I play a lot of low level pickup basketball. Out of curiosity, I wanted to simulate the difference in outcomes between shooting threes and shooting twos. Specifically, I was curious what things look like when playing to a set final score, where one team only shoots twos at a rate of 50%, and the other only shoots 3s at a rate of 33.3 percent for an even expected value.
For a simple example, let's say the teams are playing to six. My intuition told me that over a large sample size, the the two teams would win an equal number of times. The reason I ran the simulation was that I felt like maybe the team shooting twos would do better, as they more consistently scored (this aligned with my real life experience playing).
Surprisingly, I found the opposite -- in this scenario the 3-point shooting team actually wins more, at a rate of ~54%.
This number seems to decrease somewhat as the score-being-played-to increases (only selecting scores that are multiples of both 2 and 3), but remains there.
My question is why is this happening? My guess is that somehow across the probability distribution, being able to win faster is somehow an advantage, but I really understand how. I've discussed this with a few of my real life friends and we're stumped. There's also the possibility that my simulation code is wrong -- I've attached it below. Feel free to try this yourself!
Thanks for any insights, I'm quite curious on the answer here.
import random

FINAL_SCORE = 6

TWO_POINT_TEAM = "deus"
THREE_POINT_TEAM = "trey"

team_deus_wins = 0
team_trey_wins = 0
for i in range(1000000):
    team_trey_score = 0
    team_deus_score = 0

    # Give each team an even number of starting posessions
    if i < 500000:
        posession = THREE_POINT_TEAM
    else:
        posession = TWO_POINT_TEAM

    while team_deus_score < FINAL_SCORE and team_trey_score < FINAL_SCORE:
        if posession == TWO_POINT_TEAM:
            if random.randrange(0,2) == 0:
                team_deus_score += 2
            posession = THREE_POINT_TEAM
        elif posession == THREE_POINT_TEAM:
            if random.randrange(0, 3) == 0:
                team_trey_score += 3
            posession = TWO_POINT_TEAM

    if team_deus_score > team_trey_score:
        team_deus_wins += 1
    else:
        team_trey_wins += 1
    if i%100 == 0:
        # Progress logging
        print(f"Final Score: Deus: {team_deus_score}, Trey: {team_trey_score}")
        print(f"deus wins: {team_deus_wins}, trey wins: {team_trey_wins}")

# Final logging
print("final winning records:")
print(f"deus wins: {team_deus_wins}, trey wins: {team_trey_wins}")
```


An argument in favor of 3's is that it promotes offensive rebounds.  An argument in favor of 2's is partly psychological.  Whenever you fail to score, you are giving the other team an emotional breather and promoting their fast break offense.

yeah to be clear I'm focusing purely on a very very simple simulation, where possession changes after every shot

Let team A be the 3-shooters and team B the 2-shooters.
One can actually write down a series of 0's (missed) and 2's or 3's
(scored), a probability and a true/false pair for winning team A and team B.
For example these are the games of 3 up to 6 throws where team A had first possession
                         [3, 0, 3], [1/18, true, false]
                         [3, 2, 3], [1/18, true, false]
                      [3, 0, 0, 0, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [3, 2, 0, 0, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [0, 0, 3, 0, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [0, 2, 3, 0, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [3, 0, 0, 2, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [3, 2, 0, 2, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [0, 0, 3, 2, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                      [0, 2, 3, 2, 3], [1/54, true, false]
                    [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], [1/27, false, true]
                    [3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], [1/54, false, true]
                    [0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2], [1/54, false, true]
                    [0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2], [1/54, false, true]

Adding up the probabilities: If the team A starts it won with probability
2x1/18 + 8x1/54 = 7/27 = 0.25925
and it lost with probability 1x1/27 + 3x1/54 = 5/54 = 0.0925 (these two values don't
add up to 1 because after 3 to 6 attempts the game may not yet be
over).
Here are the games of 3 up to 6 throws where team B had first posesssion
                      [0, 3, 0, 3], [1/36, true, false]
                       [2, 3, 0, 3], [1/36, true, false]
                       [0, 3, 2, 3], [1/36, true, false]
                       [2, 3, 2, 3], [1/36, true, false]
                      [2, 0, 2, 0, 2], [1/18, false, true]
                      [2, 3, 2, 0, 2], [1/36, false, true]
                      [2, 0, 2, 3, 2], [1/36, false, true]
                    [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3], [1/108, true, false]
                    [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3], [1/108, true, false]

If the team B starts it won with probability 1/9 = 0.1111
and it lost with probability 13/54 = 0.2407 (these two values don't
add up to 1 because after 3 to 6 attempts the game may not yet be
over).
The bias is such that all games with up to 4 throws team A wins,
for games of 5 throws 8 of them are won by team A, 3 by team B.
For games of 6 throws 14 are won by team A, 4 by team B etc.
The likelihood that the game ends with a 3-pointer is just higher
than that it ends on a 2-pointer.

The exact win probabilities turn out to be $59/128$ for team $1$ (deus) and $69/128$ for team 2 (trey).  You can compute these probabilities via a Markov chain with states $(d,t,p)$, where $d$ is the number of points scored by team deus, $t$ is the number of points scored by team trey, and team $p$ has possession.  Let $w(d,t,p)$ be the win probability for team 1, starting from state $(d,t,p)$.  We want to compute $(w(0,0,1)+w(0,0,2))/2$.  By first-step analysis (conditioning on the first step out of each state), we obtain the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
w(0,0,1) &= \frac{1}{2}w(2,0,2) + \frac{1}{2}w(0,0,2) \\ 
w(2,0,1) &= \frac{1}{2}w(4,0,2) + \frac{1}{2}w(2,0,2) \\ 
w(4,0,1) &= \frac{1}{2}w(6,0,2) + \frac{1}{2}w(4,0,2) \\ 
w(0,3,1) &= \frac{1}{2}w(2,3,2) + \frac{1}{2}w(0,3,2) \\ 
w(2,3,1) &= \frac{1}{2}w(4,3,2) + \frac{1}{2}w(2,3,2) \\ 
w(4,3,1) &= \frac{1}{2}w(6,3,2) + \frac{1}{2}w(4,3,2) \\ 
w(0,6,1) &= 0 \\ 
w(2,6,1) &= 0 \\ 
w(4,6,1) &= 0 \\ 
w(0,0,2) &= \frac{1}{3}w(0,3,1) + \frac{2}{3}w(0,0,1) \\ 
w(2,0,2) &= \frac{1}{3}w(2,3,1) + \frac{2}{3}w(2,0,1) \\ 
w(4,0,2) &= \frac{1}{3}w(4,3,1) + \frac{2}{3}w(4,0,1) \\ 
w(6,0,2) &= 1 \\ 
w(0,3,2) &= \frac{1}{3}w(0,6,1) + \frac{2}{3}w(0,3,1) \\ 
w(2,3,2) &= \frac{1}{3}w(2,6,1) + \frac{2}{3}w(2,3,1) \\ 
w(4,3,2) &= \frac{1}{3}w(4,6,1) + \frac{2}{3}w(4,3,1) \\ 
w(6,3,2) &= 1 \\ 
\end{align}
The resulting solution is:
\begin{matrix}
d & t & p & w(d,t,p) \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 &      33/64 \\
2 & 0 & 1 &        3/4 \\
4 & 0 & 1 &      15/16 \\
0 & 3 & 1 &       3/16 \\
2 & 3 & 1 &        3/8 \\
4 & 3 & 1 &        3/4 \\
0 & 6 & 1 &          0 \\
2 & 6 & 1 &          0 \\
4 & 6 & 1 &          0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 &      13/32 \\
2 & 0 & 2 &        5/8 \\
4 & 0 & 2 &        7/8 \\
6 & 0 & 2 &          1 \\
0 & 3 & 2 &        1/8 \\
2 & 3 & 2 &        1/4 \\
4 & 3 & 2 &        1/2 \\
6 & 3 & 2 &          1 \\
\end{matrix}
So team deus wins with probability $$\frac{w(0,0,1)+w(0,0,2)}{2}=\frac{33/64+13/32}{2}=\frac{59}{128}=0.4609375,$$
in agreement with your simulation.
